# How to specify in JSON Schema one property or the other but not both?

Tags: json, powershell, schema, jsonschema

I have 4 properties: A, B, C, and D.

I'd like to have either A or B. One of them must exist. For this I created this schema that works fine.

```
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": ["A"]
    },
    {
      "required": ["B"]
    }
  ],
```

Now, I'd like to have C and D included but in a sense that I either have C or D but not both. **And I can have neither**. In other words, if I'm going to include C, then I can't include D and vice versa. However, I can also decide not to include either of them.

Something like this in my file.json

```
{
  "A": "Prop",
  "C": "Prop"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "B": "Prop",
  "D": "Prop"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "B": "Prop"
}
```

**The following should not be allowed**

You can't have A and B together.

```
{
  "A": "Prop",
  "B": "Prop"
}
```

You can't have both C and D together. But, as mentioned above, you don't have to have one of them either.

```
{
  "C": "Prop",
  "D": "Prop"
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe add an example of what the output would be and the code you currently have ?

Comment: I added a few examples. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Require one of several other properties in a JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620550/require-one-of-several-other-properties-in-a-json-schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "required": ["A"],
      "dependencies": {
        "C": {
          "not": {
            "required": ["D"]
          }
        },
        "D": {
          "not": {
            "required": ["C"]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "required": ["B"],
      "dependencies": {
        "C": {
          "not": {
            "required": ["D"]
          }
        },
        "D": {
          "not": {
            "required": ["C"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only passingly familiar with JSON schema. But assuming you can nest subschema, just write it out logically and then translate it to Boolean algebra. Then XOR is oneOf, OR is anyOf, AND is allOf, and NOT is not.

You want at one or more of these to be true:

1. A or B but not both
2. C or D but not both
3. Nothing at all. Or, "not anything".

That's:

```
(A XOR B) OR (C XOR D) OR NOT (A OR B OR C OR D)
```

That's:

```
anyOf(
    oneOf([A], [B]),
    oneOf([C], [D]),
    not(anyOf([A],[B],[C],[D]))
)
```

Comment: I don't think your suggestion takes into account the fact that I must have A or B, correct?

Comment: @jsnoobie Then just correct the logic. I didn't correctly follow what your requirements were, but the idea of what I'm presenting here that you need to do is still correct, right? You might need another nested level or totally different logic, but the core idea of (a) figure out a Boolean expression and then (b) translate that expression into the schema composition descriptors is still the same.